# How cant fixed Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function consultarSQL() on null in?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kind of stuck with this error whenever I am trying to execute my app. I am quite new with program development and I am doing this app as a way for me to learn... but I don't know where to look to find a solution. If someone gives me some guidance on where to look it will be awesome.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function consultarSQL()
> on null in
> /Users/gabriel/Documents/workspace/website_derom/classes/ActiveRecord.php:148
> Stack trace: #0
> /Users/gabriel/Documents/workspace/website_derom/admin/index.php(11):
> App\ActiveRecord::all() #1 {main} thrown in
> /Users/gabriel/Documents/workspace/website_derom/classes/ActiveRecord.php
> on line 148

This is my line of code where the error appears:

```
 // Method to activate all properties
 $properties = Property::all();
 $vendors = Vendor::all();
```

// List all records

```
public static function all() {

     $query = "SELECT * FROM " . static::$table;

     $result = self::$db->querySQL($query);
    
     return $result;
 }
```

I want to try to solve this problem to be able to run my application